# How to use C++ (in Linux) to connect MYSQL database (in WINDOWS)

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I built a database of MYSQL in windows environment, I found a lot examples C++ API for MYSQL in visual studio environment. But I am not sure that if I write a program to test the C++ API by using gcc or other tools in LINUX environment (just compile and run the program, without the platform like `eclipse`). Because in visual studio, I need to add some lib and dll for MYSQL. Shall I need to write a configuration file? How can I do this, thanks a lot!

I want to make it more clear. The database is built in WINDOWS, I want to run my c++program in Linux. So how to compile them with some lib required by MYSQL. And is there something different when I am not in visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL ships with C++ bindings, available in `cppconn/*` and `mysql_connection.h` in your include path. You will need Boost (at least `shared_ptr` and `variant`).

Check out [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-getting-started-examples.html) for examples and the reference.